# Load 64-bit integer constant via GNU extended asm constraint?

Tags: c++, assembly, clang, low-level

I've written this code in Clang-compatible "GNU extended asm":

```
namespace foreign {
    extern char magic_pointer[];
}

extern "C" __attribute__((naked)) void get_address_of_x(void)
{
    asm volatile("movq %[magic_pointer], %%rax\n\t"
                 "ret"
                 : : [magic_pointer] "p"(&foreign::magic_pointer));
}
```

I expected it to compile into the following assembly:

```
_get_address_of_x:
## InlineAsm Start
    movq    $__ZN7foreign13magic_pointerE, %rax
    ret
## InlineAsm End
    ret  /* useless but I don't think there's any way to get rid of it */
```

But instead I get this "nonsense":

```
_get_address_of_x:
movq    __ZN7foreign13magic_pointerE@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
## InlineAsm Start
movq -8(%rbp), %rax
    ret
## InlineAsm End
ret
```

Apparently Clang is assigning the value of `&foreign::magic_pointer` into `%rax` (which is deadly to a `naked` function), and then further "spilling" it onto a stack frame that doesn't even *exist*, all so it can pull it off again in the inline asm block.

So, how can I make Clang generate exactly the code I want, without resorting to manual name-mangling? I mean I could just write

```
extern "C" __attribute__((naked)) void get_address_of_x(void)
{
    asm volatile("movq  __ZN7foreign13magic_pointerE@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax\n\t"
                 "ret");
}
```

but I really don't want to do that if there's any way to help it.

Before hitting on `"p"`, I'd tried the `"i"` and `"n"` constraints; but they didn't seem to work properly with 64-bit pointer operands. Clang kept giving me error messages about not being able to allocate the operand to the `%flags` register, which seems like something crazy was going wrong.

---

For those interested in solving the "XY problem" here: I'm really trying to write a much longer assembly stub that calls off to another function `foo(void *p, ...)` where the argument `p` is set to this magic pointer value and the other arguments are set based on the original values of the CPU registers at the point this assembly stub was entered. (Hence, `naked` function.) Arbitrary company policy prevents just writing the damn thing in a `.S` file to begin with; and besides, I really *would* like to write `foreign::magic_pointer` instead of `__ZN7foreign...etc...`. Anyway, that should explain why spilling temporary results to stack or registers is strictly verboten in this context.

---

Perhaps there's some way to write

```
asm volatile(".long %[magic_pointer]" : : [magic_pointer] "???"(&foreign::magic_pointer));
```

to get Clang to insert exactly the relocation I want?

Comment: Are you building with position-independent code turned on? (`-fPIC`)

Comment: @JohnBartholomew He must be, there's no other reason for `...@GOTPCREL(%rip)` to be in there

Comment: @JohnBartholomew Yes, PIC is the default on x86-64. I suppose that means my `.long %[magic_pointer]` idea goes right out the window. But Clang should still be able to codegen a simple `leaq` or `movq` *somehow*, without all this spilling.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that using Extended asm in naked functions is explicitly disallowed in gcc (not sure about clang).  From the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Function-Attributes.html#ARM-Function-Attributes): *Only basic asm statements can safely be included in naked functions. While using extended asm or a mixture of basic asm and C code may appear to work, they cannot be depended upon to work reliably and are not supported.*

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
namespace foreign {
    extern char magic_pointer[];
}

extern "C" __attribute__((naked)) void get_address_of_x(void)
{
    asm volatile ("ret" : : "a"(&foreign::magic_pointer));
}
```

In this context, "a" is a constraint that specifies that `%rax` must be used. Clang will then load the address of `magic_pointer` into `%rax` in preparation for executing your inline asm, which is all you need.

It's a little dodgy because it's defining constraints that are unreferenced in the asm text, and I'm not sure whether that's technically allowed/well-defined - but it does work on latest clang.

On clang 3.0-6ubuntu3 (because I'm being lazy and using [gcc.godbolt.org](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22:3,%22filterAsm%22%3a%7B%22labels%22%3atrue,%22directives%22%3atrue,%22commentOnly%22%3atrue%7D,%22compilers%22%3a%5B%7B%22source%22%3a%22namespace%20foreign%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20extern%20char%20magic_pointer%5B%5D;%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cnextern%20%5C%22C%5C%22%20__attribute__%28%28naked%29%29%20void%20get_address_of_x%28void%29%5Cn%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20asm%20volatile%20%28%5C%22%5C%22%20%3a%20%3a%20%5C%22a%5C%22%28&foreign%3a%3amagic_pointer%29%29;%5Cn%7D%22,%22compiler%22%3a%22/usr/bin/clang++%22,%22options%22%3a%22-fPIC%22%7D%5D%7D)), with `-fPIC`, this is the asm you get:

```
get_address_of_x:                       # @get_address_of_x
    movq    foreign::magic_pointer@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
    ret
    ret
```

And without `-fPIC`:

```
get_address_of_x:                       # @get_address_of_x
    movl    foreign::magic_pointer, %eax
    ret
    ret
```

Comment: Note that you don't actually need the `ret`, since a ret is emitted for the function anyway. For me, it works with a blank `""` assembly block. The `ret` has the advantage of being explicit though.

Comment: @JohnBartholomew yeah, I was pondering whether to remove it or not, but decided to leave it there as I can't find any documentation to suggest that the compiler is guaranteed to add a `ret` of its own to the end of a naked function, even though gcc/clang seem to do so in practice.

Comment: The problem with this is that it would trash (AT LEAST) the `%rax` register right at the top of the function. I need to preserve all the original register values so I can pass them along to `foo`.

Comment: @Quuxplusone use a separate asm block before this one?

Comment: @Quuxplusone hold up a second... what calling convention are you using? `%rax` isn't a parameter transfer register in any x86_64 calling convention I can think of.

Comment: @je4d In the real code, it's going into `%rdx` (fourth argument register). I guess I could use two asm blocks, but that's still pretty scary. Remember, in my original toy example Clang was adding a store to `-8(%rbp)`, which is just totally broken, so I'm in this weird mental state of wanting to just rely on Clang features but at the same time knowing that I can't trust them.

Comment: @Quuxplusone I understand your dilemma! It's not too surprising that it's buggy, given how esoteric this is. If one extra instruction isn't prohibitively expensive, how about using one asm block, loading the pointer into %rax as above (which is ok as it's a scratch register), then using `mov %rax, %rdx` after you've taken care of rcx/r8/r9? btw, rdx is 3rd, rcx is 4th assuming you mean linux/bsd

Answer (score 1):

OP here.

I ended up just writing a helper `extern "C"` function to return the magic value, and then calling that function from my assembly code. I still think Clang ought to support my original approach somehow, but the main problem with that approach in my real-life case was that it didn't scale to x86-32. On x86-64, loading an arbitrary address into `%rdx` can be done in a single instruction with a `%rip`-relative `mov`. But on x86-32, loading an arbitrary address with `-fPIC` turns into just a *ton* of code, `.indirect_symbol` directives, two memory accesses... I just didn't want to *attempt* writing all that by hand. So my final assembly code looks like

```
asm volatile(
    "...save original register values...;"
    "call  _get_magic_pointer;"
    "movq  %rax, %rdx;"
    "...set up other parameters to foo...;"
    "call  _foo;"
    "...cleanup..."
    );
```

Simpler and cleaner. :)